# how to embed a user created ruby program in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am a quite a newbie in Rails and few days exp in ruby. I created a stopwatch program using threads.  But now I want to put it inside my Rails app and the view should have buttons to start,stop,resume of the stopwatch coz I am tracking an event. Can someone show **how to embed a ruby program into rails and use it from view?**

The below  program should be invoked from start/stop/resume buttons in view

**stopwatch.rb:** (It just has start method and pause method as of now)

```
class Stopwatch

def initialize
    @t_start
    @t_elapsed 
    @t_total
    @t_current
end


def start
    @t_start = Time.now
    t = Thread.new do 
          while true do
            @t_current = Time.now
            puts @t_current
            @t_elapsed = @t_current - @t_start
            puts "Time elapsed is : #{@t_elapsed.to_i} seconds"
            sleep 1
          end

     end

end

def pause
    # Stop the Thread => Sleep the Thread until Resume is pressed.
    t.kill
    # Calculate the elapsed time
        @t_elapsed = @t_current - @t_start   

    end

end

ticker = Stopwatch.new

ticker.start
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So first you could add the class in the `lib/` directory of your app.
Then the problem is that you can't `puts` things directly to the view. One solution could be to use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) for that. And then in your controller you could trigger ([doc & examples there](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pusher#triggering-events)) the data you want to send to the view.

Then you'll get the value in javascript and you can update the view.

in order to have the buttons to work, you'll also need to do that with Ajax queries and handle that in your controller